# Windows Phone 8.1 Showing progress view until async/await task finishes

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I have two tasks which download an mp3 from web address inside local storage and returns timeSpan.

```
 public async Task<TimeSpan> filedownload_Ignition_Outside()
            {
                Uri sourceIgnition_Outside = new Uri(TemporaryAddress.download_playCarSound+"Ignition_Outside");
//download and store file

                return duration_Ignition_Outside;
            }






public async Task<TimeSpan> filedownload_Idle_Outside()
    {
        Uri sourceIdle_Outside = new Uri(TemporaryAddress.download_playCarSound +"Idle_Outside");
        StorageFile destinationFileIdle_Outside;
       //download and store file

        return duration_Idle_Outside;

    }
```

Now I need to show an indeterminate progressbar in UI while downloading starts till it ends But dont know how to find the task completed?

On my **NavigatedTo** function I have set it as async and am calling 
await downloadFile();

Now inside my **downloadFile()**

```
 public async Task<TimeSpan> downloadFiles()
            {
                //ProgressShow



              var temp= await filedownload_Ignition_Outside();



                //if (filedownload_Ignition_Outside().IsCompleted)
                //{
                //    //progressStop
                //}

return temp;

    }
```

But its not executing the stop statement as it waits asynchronously how can I get the event where both task gets finished?
 Can I call **both tasks** inside my downloadFiles() method and still able to get an event for both task completion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something similar to the code given below in your `OnNavigatedTo` event.

```
          ShowProgress=true;
           downloadFiles().ContinueWith((sender) =>
            {
                this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
                   ShowProgress=false;
                );
            });
```

You need to run the   `ShowProgress=False;` in UI thread

Comment: Its showing an error as `The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))`

Comment: You need to run   ShowProgress=False; in UI thread . See edit

Comment: Now its showing the error as `An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code` inside var dispatcher

Comment: My progress is a grid with storyboard of images.

Comment: K I defined var dispatcher = CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher; at the start of OnNavigatedTo which fixed the error but Both tasks didnt get executed before progress view Collapsed how can I execute Both task and then collapse?

Comment: I have edited the code which is accessing UI thread . See now you are getting the null reference exception

Comment: Yes its working but its not waiting for completion of both tasks. My NavigatedTo return type is void hope that isnt the issue. Or do i need to call both filedownload_Ignition_Outside() and filedownload_Idle_Outside() inside downloadFiles() if so what will be its return type and how will it wait for both tasks to complete?

Comment: How you are calling two tasks right now ? I think it will work properly if you await's in downloadFiles. If it works , you can either use local varaible  to hold time spans or create another class to hold these timespans

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79622/discussion-between-jerin-and-null-pointer).